# Color Changer only working for two colors

Tags: javascript, html

How am I able to make this work with multiple colors? Also I am unable to get the links to change colors.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('ColorChanger');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var self = this,
        old_bg = this.style.background;
    
    document.body.style.background = document.body.style.background=='black'? 'white':'black';
    document.body.style.color = document.body.style.color=='lime'? 'black':'lime';
    document.alinkColor = document.linkcolor=='red'? 'black':'red';
   
})
```

```html
<div id="ColorChanger">A+</div>

<a href="#">
Test
</a>
```

Comment: what the problem withthis?

Comment: With more options I think you can't avoid loosing brevity. You can use multiple if / else if statements or a little more elegant switch statement.

Comment: The link changed color for me when I clicked the A+ and the background went black. What do you mean more colors? Are you going to have more clickable things that will change the background and links to different colors? If so, simply copy what you did for A+ for all of them. Do you want A+ to change to multiple colors? Then how so? Randomly? let the user decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all your colors in an array like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('ColorChanger');
var allColors = [];
var currentColor = 0;
allColors.push({bg:"red",front:"green"});
allColors.push({bg:"green",front:"yellow"});
allColors.push({bg:"purple",front:"white"});

div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var self = this,
        old_bg = this.style.background;

    document.body.style.background = allColors[currentColor].bg;
    document.body.style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;
   currentColor++;
if(currentColor == allColors.length) currentColor = 0;
})
```

To make it work with links you shoul use preventDefault.